# how to hide Edit button for a specific group

Tags: odoo-11

I'm using Odoo version 11 and I want to hide Edit button for some groups in this case group `attendance/manual attendance`. How can I do it?

Comment: A quick Google search gives [this](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-hide-edit-button-in-purchase-order-for-specific-states-128804) as a possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can done this by creating a security file in your module 'ir.model.access.csv'
1.id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
2.access_hr_attendance_manual_id,access_hr_attendance_manual,model_hr_attendance,hr_attendance.group_hr_attendance,1,0,0,0

Answer (score 2):

```
        <record id="inherit_attendance_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">attendance.form</field>
        <field name="model">attendance</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="attendance."/>
        <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('base.group_system') ])]"/><tree edit=false/>
</record>
```

Comment: Inherit form int which you want to hide edit button and apply group on it so that that form is visible for some groups.